# Giving different colors to a p tag

Tags: html, styles

I'm trying to define different colors based on different conditions.
I have the following code:

```
<p 
style="@((i == 1) ? ("color:#black;") : ("color:#white;"))" </p>
```

how can I define different colors for different `i's`.

For example if `I==1` then style is **black**, if `I` is 2 then style is **blue**...
I tried if then else but I couldn't make it...

Answer (score 0):

On CSS3 you can use:

```
p:nth-child(2)
{
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

And much more!

[See W3 documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp) and [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child).

Answer (score 0):

i think that you want to this:

```
if(i==1){
 <p style="background-color: #ff0000"> here goes anything you want in black</p>
}
else{
 <p style="background-color: #3852D6"> here goes anything you want in blue </p>
}
```

if this is not what you looking for, maybe we can help you better if you show us your code an explain it.
i hope i helped you!..